# Formating of csv data with python data frames

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a some csv data which I want to reformat as

[image]

I want to change this format with Data1-4 as column names and Value 1-4 as values besides data A and B

I have millions of rows, where I don't want to loop it. I am working with python data frame.

Please suggest the best way to do this as looping for millions loop will take huge time and I want to complete the task in the best possible way in terms of performance.

Some more sample data which I am trying to do:

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you edit your post a little and reexplain your current format / expected format. It is difficult to see the difference as it is.

Comment: Sorry for the Format provided earlier. Updated the current and expected format.

Answer (score 2):

If input is `Series` with 3 level `MultiIndex` use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print (s.index.nlevels)
3

df = s.unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Or if input is 4 column `DataFrame` first repalce missing values in first 2 columns by forward filling and then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
print (len(df.columns))
4

df.columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']
cols = ['Col1','Col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
df = df.set_index(['Col1','Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: above code gives me some idea to approach but doesn't gives the desired output. I need to transpose 3rd and 4th column of my current format and this will add a separate column for each data I have. In my above example, I am giving input of 4 columns where I want to transpose last two columns. As I am having 4 rows of data so my expected format will have 2+4 columns. This will vary if the number of data increases.

Comment: @Vaybhava - Are data confidental? If not, is possible share `df.to_pickle('data.pkl')` ?

Comment: Added few screen shots which may be useful. I created this as a sample data as the data I have is highly confidential.

Comment: @Vaybhava - OK, is possible send me sample not confidental sample data saved in  `data.pkl` to my eamil or send link to dropbox or gdocs ?

Comment: @Vaybhava - Also `coupon` have no value?

Comment: sent. Please check

Comment: yes there are few columns where I don't have any data. Again My actual data is huge like 10 million * 40 (rows * col).

Comment: @Vaybhava - Check email.

Comment: Thanks ! It is working fine. Sent one more query on email. Please check.